# Reading Features From A Google Fusion Tables Table - OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, google-fusion-tables

Why doesn't this example work? http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/fusiontables.html
I would like to do something similar but i can not find any other example how to display points from Google Fusion Table on the OpenLayers map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message on console is:

```
Access Not Configured.
Please use Google Developers Console to activate the API for your project.
```

At bottom of  [example page](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/examples/fusiontables.html) on openlayers.org posted in question you can see this text:

```
View the fusiontables.js source to see how this is done. 
You will need to get your own apikey from Google's API Console for this to 
function on your domain.
```

Please see this [link](https://code.google.com/apis/console/?pli=1) to setup Google's API Console

EDIT:
An example post request

```
https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=%22select+*+from+1g5DrXcdotCiO_yffkdW0zhuJk0a1i80SPvERHI8%22&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

The above from Google API console gives:

```
{
"kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
"columns": [
"Route",
"Reverse",
"Times Flown",
"Line String",
"DepAirport",
"ArrAirport",
"First Time",
"Last Time",
"Distance",
"Time",
"Route Airline List",
"Route Year List"
],
"rows": [
[
"CLT-MSP",
"",
"2",
{
"geometry": {
"type": "LineString",
"coordinates": [
[
-80.943139,
35.214,
0
],
[
-81.2867027228329,
35.5424123906216,
0
],
[
-81.6334656409202,
35.8701977680468,
0
.....
..
```

And Openlayers can take it from here.

Comment: I'm a little bit lost. I have a code as follows: `layers: [
        new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM(),
        new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Vectors", {
            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.Script({
                url: "https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query",
                params: {sql: "select * from 1g5DrXcdotCiO_yffkdW0zhuJk0a1i80SPvERHI8"},
           format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({...`      and where do I put my own apikey from Google's API Console

Comment: this is my example: [link](http://new-bucket-fa0e35a5.s3.amazonaws.com/cliente/indexv7.html), and demolayer4 should be from Google Fusion Table

Comment: Did you registered on Google's API console? and first try the example hosted on openlayers

Comment: now i have API key. should i put iy in my html file?

Comment: select * from YOURAPIKEY

Comment: no, doesn't work :( but I think that select * from DOCID. In this example the link of tha table is [https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1g5DrXcdotCiO_yffkdW0zhuJk0a1i80SPvERHI8](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1g5DrXcdotCiO_yffkdW0zhuJk0a1i80SPvERHI8) and in the code `"select * from 1g5DrXcdotCiO_yffkdW0zhuJk0a1i80SPvERHI8"`

Comment: Hi, updated answer.